# Sharing instances across multiple DataFlow jobs/pipelines - is it possible?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is it possible to submit X separate jobs/pipelines using the `DataflowPipelineRunner`runner (async), and have the jobs share the worker pool rather then spin up and tear down individual ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not yet -- though it's on our radar as a useful feature. How useful would this be for you?

Comment: It would be really useful. Our use case is we've got multiple sources of data coming DFP (Impressions, Clicks, ActiveViews etc.), and we need to transform the dat before loading into BigQuery. The pipeline's we've built to handle each source of data are almost identical except for the format of the files. We intend to kick off all the jobs async and process in parallel. So, it would be awesome if the jobs could share a common worker pool rather than each one having to spin up its own and tear it down after.

Comment: We fully manage the VMs for each pipeline -- creation, resizing/scheduling, and teardown. Our goal is to be able to resize workerpools and assign tasks in such a way that workers are rarely idle. (We've got limited resizing available now, and a number of improvements coming soon.) So in that case, the benefits of sharing a pool across pipelines become limited.

Comment: Another thing to note is that a single pipeline can have multiple, disconnected subgraphs, so you could have one pipeline that does all three of these transformations. But this does come with the caveat that a failure in one transformation would cause the entire pipeline to fail.

Comment: That sounds good. How do I pragmatically have one pipeline using multiple, disconnected subgraphs? (I'm fine with the caveat)

Comment: When you create your pipeline p, you can start multiple subgraphs with multiple p.apply(<first subgraph step>)

Comment: @Frances how it looks like now? I mean - is it still on your radar?